# Getting the location from an IP address from client location

Tags: php

```
How to get all detail about system using ip address like
remote_address , address detail ....etc  from user location  in php
and    populate some restrict data that is not available in this
particular    area
```

I want to get the client IP address who uses my website

Comment: I think the reason is that you have not made an attempt yourself. "Please find a service and write my code"-type-of-question.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this code and i get city,state,latitude and longitude information using below code.

```
<?php function ip_details($IPaddress) 
      {
        $json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$IPaddress}");
        $details    = json_decode($json);
        return $details;
      }
      $IPaddress  =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

      $details    =   ip_details("49.248.240.116");

     print_r($details);

?>
```

output is:

```
stdClass Object ( [ip] => 49.248.240.116 [hostname] => No Hostname [city] => Mumbai [region] => Maharashtra [country] => IN [loc] => 18.9750,72.8258 [org] => AS55441 D 26/2 TTC INDUSTRIAL AREA MIDC SANPADA )
```

Comment: i have to use wordpress please give me how i add and where i add

Comment: write ip_details function in function.php file and call it from where you want location information using other three lines.

Answer (score -1):

You can use: https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/

install and then you can use something like these shortcodes:

[geoip_detect2 property="country"] -> Germany

[geoip_detect2 property="country.isoCode"] -> de

[geoip_detect2 property="country" lang="de"] -> Deutschland

[geoip_detect2 property="country" lang="fr,de"] -> Allemagne

[geoip_detect2 property="country.confidence" default="default value"] -> default value

also see: https://github.com/yellowtree/wp-geoip-detect/wiki/API-Documentation

Comment: yes i tried but it is installed not working properly  https://wordpress.org/plugins/ip2location-tags/   bboni thank you for your answer

Comment: do you want to code it yourself or do you want to use a plugin

Comment: I want to use a plugin

Comment: See updated answer, and please let us know if it worked or not.